# Guardia di finanza, polizia, e carabinieri

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, single-words

Buongiorno,

Ho visto in giro delle macchine che sembrano essere la polizia o i carabinieri ma c'è invece scritto sulla porta "guardia di finanza". Ma questo che cos'ha a che fare con la finanza? Dopo tutto tutto la finanza non è quell'argomento che riguarda gli stock market? Perché addetti al controllo del pagamento delle tasse necessiterebbero di una macchina speciale?

Grazie.

Grazie.

Comment: Questa domanda non riguarda la lingua italiana (bensì un'istituzione italiana: sarebbe come chiedere che cos'è il Senato o come si cucina l'amatriciana) e per giunta la risposta si trova in 3 secondi con un qualsiasi motore di ricerca.

Comment: controllano che paghi le tasse, e altri reati connessi alla finanza, quindi il nome è pertinente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Italia la Guardia di Finanza (o GdF o Fiamme Gialle) è un corpo di polizia che si occupa di reati economico-finanziari, tra cui: evasione fiscale, contrabbando, frodi, falsificazione di valuta, gioco d'azzardo, oltre a immigrazione clandestina e traffico di stupefacenti.

Fa parte delle forze armate (è un corpo militare come i Carabinieri, anche se dipende dal Ministero dell'Economia); ti rimando alla pagina di Wikipedia per maggiori informazioni.

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardia_di_Finanza